# How to change Default Port used by PostgreSQL 9.5 on CentOS 7?

Tags: postgresql, centos7

Does someone have an idea about how to change default port for PostgreSQL 9.5, I did the same on previous versions and I just modify the following files:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/postgresql.conf
```

---

```
listen_addresses = '*'

port = 4000
```

---

```
/etc/phpPgAdmin/config.inc.php
```

---

```
$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';

$conf['servers'][0]['port'] = 4000;
```

---

I am using phpPgAdmin to check out the Database from the web, it works with default port, but it doesn't work when not using the default port, also in the terminal i get this error after restarting postgresql service:

```
[root@cos7psql01 system]# su - postgres
Last login: Sun Jan 17 12:38:27 CST 2016 on pts/0
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

*Port set to 4000 is just an example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config setup looks ok, however how you are trying to connect to the service doesn't. If you don't specify a custom port, it will try to connect via the default port.

Try using the `-p` flag to define that you want to connect via a specific port:

```
psql -p 4000
```

Comment: Yeah you are right that solution helps to me, thanks!